# Apache include Javascript in header

Tags: javascript, apache, plesk

I need to place a `Javascript` file into every site I or a subscriber is hosting on my server with Plesk Onyx /Apache2. I can add  additional Apache directives at the Plesk Onyx (version 17.5.3) backend but I don't know how to integrate properly trough apache directives?!
I can include these directives at the subscription level of plesk, so that's a rule for all subscribers of the plesk server...

So in general, I only need to know how to include a JS file with additional Apache directives. Any idea?

Comment: Javascript gets included inside an `html` page and can't be included in your apache config! not sure whats the goal here!?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/684359/is-it-possible-to-replace-content-on-every-page-passed-through-a-proxy-similar-t

Answer (score 0):

As @Deano said no sure of the goal but if you want to adding js and using SSI from apache you need first setting file configuration httpd.conf, or the file .htaccess in root of /var/www/.htaccess

This directive tell to Apache that you want to search the directives SSI.

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/javascript .js
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .jxjson
```

considered that jxjson extension is js is the condition needed for the SSI directives will apply.

Comment: The goal is to offer free webhosting with plesk and to make this possible, every visitor that gets on a domain hosted by my free plesk service is forced to load this JS script in background (the JS file places ads etc.). 
Any idea what could be the best way of implementation. I'm not very experienced in coding otherwise i would maybe code a Plesk extension myself.

Comment: I was searching for something like mod_layout

Comment: @vioman If you are looking for a solution as addon for plesk you can buy whmcs license that do the job for you or your boss, regards.

Comment: Hello, no its just for me ;)
i found: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/mod_layout-troubles.64904/
maybe this is a solution but i cant figure out how or where to place AccessFileName directive so that it takes effect for any vHost i use?

Comment: Ok found it xD
sorry guys but i never use apache... only nginx

Comment: @vioman to add directive go to my post htaccess (where is you site) or httpd.conf in you plesk apache configuration.